# how do i search for part of a string in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have someone search a string that is a key in a dictionary and i want to search for it but if he puts only part of the string it dosen't find it.

this is the code:(i already have ometz = 0524667997 in the dictionary)

```
everything = {ometz: 0524667997}    
pick = raw_input('what are you searching for? ')
if pick == 'l':
    check = raw_input('what is the name? ')
    if check in everything:
        print everything[check]
```

so if i will search 'omet' it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Substring checking will not work against dict key.